# Elastic Beanstalk cannot find the server.js file

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, github-actions

I'm trying to deploy my **Angular** application through [GitHub Actions](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/about-github-actions) to Elastic Beanstalk. I'm using this [GitHub actions](https://github.com/einaregilsson/beanstalk-deploy) for the deploying to ELB.

My problem is, the deployment is failing as the ELB cannot find the `server.js` file. I have tried adding `server.js` file into the **deploy.zip** file, but then it throws a different error.

I get it, it needs `server.js` to run, but when I download the build for the same application which is pushed to ELB using **Travis CI**. It doesn't throw such error and CI/CD is working just fine.

Here is the error logged by ELB *(when `server.js` is not added to deploy.zip)*:

```
throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/var/app/current/server.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! climber-mentee-fe@1.0.1 aws: `node server.js && npm run serve`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the climber-mentee-fe@1.0.1 aws script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

> climber-mentee-fe@1.0.1 aws /var/app/current
> node server.js && npm run serve
```

I'm also attaching my `package.json` and `main.yml`(for CI) files.

**package.json**:

```
"name": "climber-mentee-fe",
"version": "1.0.1",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "serve": "ng serve --configuration=dev",
    "start:staging": "gulp set --env=staging && concurrently --kill-others \"node server.js\" \"npm run serve\"",
    "start:prod": "gulp set --env=prod && concurrently --kill-others \"node server.js\" \"npm run serve\"",
    "build": "ng build --configuration=production",
    "test": "ng test",
    "aws": "node server.js && npm run serve",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  ...
  ...
 }
```

**main.yml**:

```
name: My application CI

on:
  push:
    branches:
    - dry-run-actions

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [10.x]

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1

    - name: Node ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}

    - name: Installing NPM
      run: npm install

    - name: Building application and copying package.json to dist
      run: npm run build && cp package.json dist/

    - name: Generate deployment package
      run: cd dist && zip -r ../deploy.zip ./*

    - name: Beanstalk Deploy for App
      uses: einaregilsson/beanstalk-deploy@v3
      with:
        aws_access_key: ${{secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY}}
        aws_secret_key: ${{secrets.AWS_SECRET_KEY}}
        application_name: my-app
        environment_name: my-app-env
        region: ap-south-1
        version_label: 455
        deployment_package: deploy.zip
```

**Screen of var/app/current**
[image]

Comment: please add screenshot of files in /var/app/current.

Comment: @matesio Where can I find `/var/app/current`? I'm pretty new to AWS thing

Comment: @matesio I've added the screenshot

Comment: okay, it seems you are trying to serve a SPA, I would suggest you to use s3 and CloudFront to serve your application. if you want to do this on elastic beanstalk don't create a minified build and simply place your application there. If you want to create a minified build, you will need to change nginx.conf to server static site instead of hosting as "npm start."

Comment: @matesio I've just figured out the solution and posted the answer below.

Comment: that's the thing you don't need server.js when you're moving forward with minified build.

Comment: @matesio Thanks for giving me the idea to check `var/app/current`. That helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out finally.

We need to zip the complete root folder excluding the `node_modules` folder. So, in that case, I won't need any `server.js` and `package.json` included inside the `dist` folder.

Updated yml snippet

```
- name: Building application
  run: npm run build

- name: Generate deployment package
  run: zip -r deploy.zip * -x ./node_modules
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by adding an `.ebextensions` directory containing a single file named `python.config`. The contents of that file are:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: server:app
```

This file tells Elastic Beanstalk that the FastAPI application is located in the `server.py` file and is named `app`.